# How to extract and append path in C using wchar_t*

Tags: c, winapi, unicode

I want to extract the path from `GetModuleFileNameW` and then to append `"\hello.dll"` to it (Without making `"\\\\"`). How to do that? (I'm not good with Unicode functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're really working with paths, use the [`PathAppendW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773565.aspx) function. Note that you do this by appending `"hello.dll"` -- the backslash will be added if required by `PathAppendW`.

Alternately, you could write your own function pretty easily. Here's an example I threw together in 5 minutes in terms of `std::wstring`s

```
std::wstring PathAppend(const std::wstring& lhs, const std::wstring& rhs)
{
    if (lhs.empty())
    {
        return rhs;
    }
    else if (rhs.empty())
    {
        return lhs;
    }
    std::wstring result(lhs);
    if (*lhs.rbegin() == L'\\')
    {
        result.append(rhs.begin() + (rhs[0] == L'\\'), rhs.end());
    }
    else
    {
        if (rhs[0] != L'\\')
        {
            result.push_back(L'\\');
        }
        result.append(rhs);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to extract the path first?

Comment: @blez: I don't know what you mean. You asked how to append a file to a path. That's the function that you use to do that. I don't know what you mean otherwise.

Comment: GetModuleFileNameW returns the whole module file name, as far as I know. Like C:\Dir\SomeFile.dll" and the file must be stripped to get the path only - "C:\Dir". I must do that first before I concatenate the remaining filename.

Comment: @blez: Sounds like you want [PathRemoveFileSpecW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773748.aspx)